# iOS Programming memory issue with ALAssets enumeration with ARC

Tags: memory, automatic-ref-counting, enumeration, alassetslibrary

I wish to enumerate over my album, but when i test the app on my device, the app crashes after 30 seconds. when I used Instrument, i discovered that ARC doesn't autorelease the assets, so every time it deals with an image, it allocates the image size. My main goal is showing only device's screenshots. so lets say i have 1000 photos, after 30 images i get 30MB allocation, which causes the crash. How do I explicitly release the memory?

Here is my code:

```
[self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    if (result) {

        ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [result defaultRepresentation];

        // Retrieve the image orientation from the ALAsset
        UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientationUp;

        NSNumber* orientationValue = [result valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"];

        if (orientationValue != nil) {
            orientation = [orientationValue intValue];
        }

        CGFloat scale  = 1;
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]
                                             scale:scale orientation:orientation];

        if ( image.size.height/2==screenHeight && image.size.width/2==screenWidth)
            [self.assets addObject:result];
    }
}];
```

I think default representation causes the malloc.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what happens when you try "`image = nil;`" right after adding the ALAsset to your assets array?

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. probably due to strong type issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've discovered that UIImage objects can take up a ***lot*** of memory when they're created.

Instead of creating UIImage objects, why not use API's that ALAsset provides to you that don't hog memory.  For example, you can get the image [`dimensions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/dimensions) (I've linked the Apple documentation for you).

Also, this line:

```
if ( image.size.height/2==screenHeight && image.size.width/2==screenWidth)
```

seems a little dangerous to me.  Unless you control all the images that are being loaded, any full resolution image is very likely to be a different size than exactly 1/2 of the screen height and width.

Comment: dimension absolutely worked! Thank you Michael. I only need screenshots and theyre dimension are equal to the device's dimension.

Comment: @Michael do you have a reference for your claim that ALAsset* doesn't hog memory? thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlexSpencer ; An ALAsset object is just an object that points to the (sometimes massive) UIImage files. By itself, an ALAsset object contains properties, and if we really want to be pedantic, perhaps `defaultRepresentation` is sizable [it's a "`ALAssetRepresentation`" object](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ALAssetRepresentation).

Comment: Actually, all of this is old news anyways since iOS 8 introduced the new [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408) which replaces the ALAsset stuff.